# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, how to solve this error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. I am encountering the error "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

I have tried all possible solutions I could come up with but am unable to solve the problem. It would be great if someone could help!

I have attached my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGEE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ItemsActivity" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAgUK9uXUxu2f5rLdZGCsh5wy4pTn2JXMA" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="activity_maps" />
        <activity android:name=".MarkerActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The gradle file is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.access"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Details about the problem will appear in the Gradle tool above the "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" message. If you cannot interpret those details, please add them to your question.

Comment: Post your full error logcat